# Another word for "give in to somebody"?

Tags: word-request

My dictionary lists a few where the translation is the same but I dont think they have the correct meaning. "Relent" "retreat" "concede" ( maybe this one?)

Comment: ***Give in (to sth)***: 
​
to finally agree to something that someone wants after first refusing:
*If you want them to give in you'll have to offer them more than that.*
​
Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: If you want something **informal**, you can use "**cave in**" - to give in to someone or something, yield. ("*Finally, the manager caved in to the customer's demands*". "*I refuse to cave in under pressure from my opponent*"). I hear this especially when game developers cave in to players requests when they whine about features that make the game too hard for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> give in

has the meaning of reluctantly agreeing, converting over, after putting up some sort of resistance.

Two other words with the same implied meanings are

> acquiesce
>   surrender

Answer (score 1):

You could also try: Yield, concede (defeat), admit (defeat), give up, back down or throw in the towel.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is succumb which means to give in to a force stronger than oneself. It suggests almost powerlessness. Here is the definition:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/succumb